# How can I get a list of all permutations of two column combination based on another column's value?

Tags: python, pandas

My end goal is to create a [Force-Directed graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) with d3 that shows clusters of users that utilize certain features in my applications. To do this, I need to create a set of "links" that have the following format (taken from the above link):

```
{"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1}
```

To get to this step though, I start with a pandas dataframe that looks like this. How can I generate a list of permutations of `APP_NAME`/`FEAT_ID` combinations for each `USER_ID`?

```
        APP_NAME      FEAT_ID   USER_ID  CNT  
280     app1          feature1  user1    114  
2622    app2          feature2  user1    8  
1698    app2          feature3  user1    15  
184     app3          feature4  user1    157  
2879    app2          feature5  user1    7  
3579    app2          feature6  user1    5  
232     app2          feature7  user1    136  
295     app2          feature8  user1    111  
2620    app2          feature9  user1    8  
2047    app3         feature10  user2    11  
3395    app2          feature2  user2    5  
3044    app2         feature11  user2    6  
3400    app2         feature12  user2    5
```

Expected Results:

Based on the above dataframe, I'd expect `user1` and `user2` to generate the following permutations

```
user1:
    app1-feature1 -> app2-feature2, app2-feature3, app3-feature4, app2-feature5, app2-feature6, app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature2 -> app2-feature3, app3-feature4, app2-feature5, app2-feature6, app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature3 -> app3-feature4, app2-feature5, app2-feature6, app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app3-feature4 -> app2-feature5, app2-feature6, app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature5 -> app2-feature6, app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature6 -> app2-feature7, app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature7 -> app2-feature8, app2-feature9
    app2-feature8 -> app2-feature9

user2:
    app3-feature10 -> app2-feature2, app2-feature11, app2-feature12
    app2-feature2  -> app2-feature11, app2-feature12
    app2-feature11 -> app2-feature12
```

From this, I'd expect to be able to generate the expected inputs to D3, which would look like this for `user2`.

```
{"source": "app3-feature10", "target": "app2-feature2"}
{"source": "app3-feature10", "target": "app2-feature11"}
{"source": "app3-feature10", "target": "app2-feature12"}
{"source": "app2-feature2", "target": "app2-feature11"}
{"source": "app2-feature2", "target": "app2-feature12"}
{"source": "app2-feature11", "target": "app2-feature12"}
```

How can I generate a list of permutations of `APP_NAME`/`FEAT_ID` combinations for each `USER_ID` in my dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at making some tuples out of your dataframe and then using something like `itertools.permutations` to create all the permutations, and then from there, craft your dictionaries as you need:

```
import itertools

allUserPermutations = {}

groupedByUser = df.groupby('USER_ID')
for k, g in groupedByUser:

    requisiteColumns = g[['APP_NAME', 'FEAT_ID']]

    # tuples out of dataframe rows
    userCombos = [tuple(x) for x in requisiteColumns.values]

    # this is a generator obj
    userPermutations = itertools.permutations(userCombos, 2)

    # create a list of specified dicts for the current user
    userPermutations = [{'source': s, 'target': tar for s, tar in userPermutations]

    # store the current users specified dicts
    allUserPermutations[k] = userPermutations
```

If the permutations don't return the desired behavior, you could try some other combinatoric generators [found here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#module-itertools). Hopefully, this kind of strategy works (I don't have a pandas-enabled REPL to test it, at the moment). Best of luck!